# Does XAMPP support Curl currently in 2021?

Tags: php, api, curl, xampp

Does XAMPP comem with curl compatibility? My end goal is to be able to pull API data from Facebook into my web application I'm currently testing using XAMPP's web server solution.

I've googled around about XAMPP and Curl but the tutorials are all +/- 10 years old and haven't helped. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge latest version of `xampp` come with `curl` enabled by default.

You may check if `curl` is enabled or not using `phpinfo();` function of PHP.

it will output like [image]

If it not enabled you may go to `php.ini` file and check if `extension=curl` is not commented. if its commented then remove the commment and restart your `xampp Apache service`. it would work.

Comment: awesome thanks. That helped and curl was indeed enabled!